# Custom image sizes

Tags: media, images

I noticed lots of articles on how to add custom sizes for images (media).

But how would I be able to add a custom size such as "width:100% and height:auto" this way it will make sure the images are responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I don't know what articles you've read - however, I'm pretty much sure they are about WordPress' functionality to automatically **resize** images after upload, as in *actual pixel width and height*.
What you are talking about, is **scaling** (via CSS).

So in short: these are two different pair of shoes.

Comment: sorry for confusing. when I add an image in a post currently it has 3 options for the size; thumbnail, medium, large. If I use any of them it is not responsive. so manually I need to go to the image html and change the width to 100% and height to auto. I want to have an option that has those parameters already in place, how would I do it? hope it is clear now.